# Display tags in string in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags

I want to display [Day,Date,Time] as in tag in email. So when the email is sent to all users, the particular Datetime is set to all users replacing that tag based on the different datetime, the users have booked the tickets. Likewise User 1 has booked the ticket for Tuesday, 12 February 2018, 07:00 PM and similarly User 2 for other day date and time.

I'm using AjaxToolKitEditor for email formatting.

```
while (DC.dbReader.Read())
            {
                Member member = new Member();
                member.strEmailAddress = DC.dbReader["MemberEmail"].ToString();

                Times time = new Times();
                time.dtDateTime = (DateTime)DC.dbReader["DateTime"]; //Have date and time for individual user 
                lstmember.Add(member);
            }

   foreach(var item in lstmember)
            {
              EmailDispatcher.SendEmail(item.strEmailAddress, txt_subject.Text, HTMLEditor.Content);
            }
```

At runtime i want to replace the `htmleditor.content` containg that tag with the actual datetime of booking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Replace** method of HTMLEditor.Content for [Day, Date, Time] with DateTime.Now.ToString("DateFormat")

Your sample code should be

```
 while (DC.dbReader.Read())
                {
                    Member member = new Member();
                    member.strEmailAddress = DC.dbReader["MemberEmail"].ToString();

                    Times time = new Times();
                    time.dtDateTime = (DateTime)DC.dbReader["DateTime"]; //Have date and time for individual user 
                    member.strDateTime = time.dtDateTime.ToString("d, dd-MM-yy, hh:mm tt"); //If you want 24H then use HH.
                    lstmember.Add(member);
                }

       foreach(var item in lstmember)
                {
                  EmailDispatcher.SendEmail(item.strEmailAddress, txt_subject.Text, HTMLEditor.Content.Replace("[Day, Date, Time]",item.strDateTime ));
                }
```

Comment: What about the tag which i want to display for [day, date, time]?

Comment: @user100020 for that you need to put combo box on top of the HTMLEditor and put the one button Add when user click on Add then append that selected tag into the HTMLEditor content.

Comment: HTMLEditor.Content.Replace() is not replacing the content

Comment: Basically if you have write this line alone like **HTMLEditor.Content.Replace()**  then it will not work you must need to pass this into EmailDispatcher.SendEmail parameters or assign this to any variable or self like this  **HTMLEditor.Content.Replace()=HTMLEditor.Content.Replace()**

Comment: Yes, i've initialized another string and this time it replace the content. But the answer remains incomplete. The tags to use in string which will be readable only.

Comment: If you don't want to allowed to edit the #tag then you must need to write your own JavaScript for disable this. other wise simple solution is put combo box on top of the HTMLEditor and put the one button Add when user click on Add then append that selected tag into the HTMLEditor content.